# Munit not working when deploying project on Azure devops however it's working in APS?

Tags: mulesoft, munit

Hi All am getting as "Could not find artifact com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.1.5 in maven-central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/)"

**Am calling it from yaml as " mvn test -Dmunit.test=test-suite.xml"**

Plesae find below my pom.xml
    
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.accenture</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>dataweave-2-basics</artifactId>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>
    <name>dataweave-2-basics</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <cloudhubusername>${envusername}</cloudhubusername>
        <cloudhubpassword>${envpassword}</cloudhubpassword>
        <app.runtime>4.2.0</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.2.7</mule.maven.plugin.version>
          <munit.version>2.2.4</munit.version>
    </properties>


    <build>

        <plugins>
         <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                  <cloudHubDeployment>
                   <uri>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com</uri> 
                   <!--<deploymentType>cloudhub</deploymentType>-->
                   <applicationName>${cloudhubAppName}</applicationName>
                   <muleVersion>4.2.0</muleVersion>
                   <username>${cloudhubusername}</username>
                   <password>${cloudhubpassword}</password>
                   <workerType>Micro</workerType>
                <!--            <redeploy>true</redeploy> -->
                   <environment>Sandbox</environment>
                </cloudHubDeployment>
                  <classifier>mule-application</classifier> 
                </configuration>
              <executions>
                        <execution>
                                <id>deploy</id>
                                <phase>deploy</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                                </goals>
                            <configuration>
                            <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                        </executions> 
            </plugin>
           <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${munit.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <goal>coverage-report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>
                        <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </coverage>
                    <runtimeVersion>4.1.5</runtimeVersion>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-file-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

   <repositories>
        <repository>
           <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
           <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
           <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/maven</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
           <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
           <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
           <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
           <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
           <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
           <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
           <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
           <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
           <layout>default</layout>
           <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
           <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
           <name>mulesoft snapshots repository</name>
           <layout>default</layout>
           <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
           <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
           <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
           <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/maven</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
           <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
           <name>MuleSoft Snapshot Repository</name>
           <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
           <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

That artifact is in the MuleSoft Enterprise repository. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb#referencing-mulesofts-enterprise-repositories for instructions on how to add the repository.

Note that you have to be a customer of MuleSoft to have credentials for the Enterprise repository.

UPDATE: this KB article mentions this issue: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Unable-to-find-the-dependency-com-mulesoft-mule-distributions-mule-runtime-impl-bom-pom-when-building-through-maven

Comment: Thanks for your reply @aled. Can we not use this without having customer with Mulesoft or without Mulesoft credentials?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible. I also found this issue mentioned in a MuleSoft KB with the same solution. Having said that, are you using any enterprise features in the application?

Comment: No we are not using any enterprise features.